Kivy - BoxLayouts' height in RecycleView
environment:
Python: 3.11.5
Kivy: 2.3.0
I'm creating an app with RecycleView. This is my main.py:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from functools import partial

class MyRecycleViewItem(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        def _update_rect(rect, instance, value):
            rect.pos = instance.pos
            rect.size = instance.size

        self.clear_widgets()
        with self.canvas.before:
            self.canvas.before.clear()
            if index % 2 == 0:
                Color(rgba=(0, .5, 0, 1))
            else:
                Color(rgba=(1, 1, 1, 1))
            rect = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)
        self.bind(size=partial(_update_rect, rect), pos=partial(_update_rect, rect))

        for text in data['texts']:
            self.add_widget(MyLabel(text=text))

        return super(MyRecycleViewItem, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

class MyLabel(Label):
    pass

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = (
            {'texts': ('L1-1', 'L1-2')},
            {'texts': ('L2-1', 'L2-2', 'L2-3')},
            {'texts': ('L3-1', 'L3-2')},
            {'texts': ('L4-1', 'L4-2', 'L4-3')},
            {'texts': ('L5-1', 'L5-2')},
            {'texts': ('L6-1', 'L6-2', 'L6-3')},
            {'texts': ('L7-1', 'L7-2')},
            {'texts': ('L8-1', 'L8-2', 'L8-3')},
            {'texts': ('L9-1', 'L9-2')},
            {'texts': ('L10-1', 'L10-2', 'L10-3')},
            {'texts': ('L11-1', 'L11-2')},
            {'texts': ('L12-1', 'L12-2', 'L12-3')}
        )

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()

and main.kv:
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'MyRecycleViewItem'

    RecycleBoxLayout: 
        orientation: 'vertical'
        default_size: None, None
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

<MyRecycleViewItem>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_y: None

<MyLabel>
    color: .4, .5, .6, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size: self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1]

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .1, .2, .3, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

The codes give a result like this:
Screen 1(https://i.sstatic.net/AkMz2H8J.png)
I want it to make the BoxLayouts' height just for Labels inside, in other words not to show green and white backgrounds, so I changed the kv file like this:
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'MyRecycleViewItem'

    RecycleBoxLayout: 
        orientation: 'vertical'
        default_size: None, None
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

<MyRecycleViewItem>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height # <- Added! 

<MyLabel>
    color: .4, .5, .6, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size: self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1]

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .1, .2, .3, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

This returns:
Screen 2(https://i.sstatic.net/J5hCM72C.png)
How can I fit the heights?
I'll appreciate any of your helps!
